# realloc( ): Invalid next size

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, realloc

Minimal reproducible example:

> prog.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  size_t bufsiz = 4, tmp;
  char *buffer;

  for (buffer = malloc(bufsiz), tmp = 0; buffer[tmp] = fgetc(stdin); ++tmp) {
    if (bufsiz == tmp && !realloc(buffer, bufsiz *= 2))
      return 1;
} }
```

> Compile and run

```
gcc prog.c -o prog

echo duck | ./prog
realloc(): Invalid next size
Aborted
```

I have read  many similar threads but could not find the solution.

Comment: You are not reassigning buffer. So this call  !realloc(buffer, bufsiz *= 2) does not make a great sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realloc` returns a pointer to the allocated space, which may be equal to the previous pointer or may be a new value or a null pointer. You cannot simply call `realloc(buffer, bufsiz *= 2)`; you must use the return value as the new address.

When `realloc` returns a new value, the previous memory is no longer allocated and should not be used.

You will also need a different stopping condition for the loop. Using `buffer[tmp] = fgetc(stdin)` as the test will cause it to stop when a null character is read, but you should not expect a null character to mark the end of the input. `fgetc` will return `EOF` when the end of input is reached, but `EOF` is generally not representable as a `char` value. You must store (in an `int`) and test the return value of `fgetc` before assigning it to a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this assignment

```
buffer[tmp] = fgetc(stdin)
```

can result in accessing the memory outside the array.

For example let's assume that initially `bufsiz`  is equal to `1`.

So after the first iteration of the loop the variable `tmp` will be equal to `1` due to the expression `++tmp` in the loop statement. And in the condition of the loop there will be

```
buffer[1] = fgetc(stdin)
```

However `1` is not a valid index in this case.

And moreover the user can interrupt the input. In this case the function `fgetc` will return `EOF` that you will try to store in the character array.

The second problem is that in this expression

```
!realloc(buffer, bufsiz *= 2)
```

the returned value of the function `realloc` that is the address of the new allocated memory is lost. So the pointer `buffer` will be invalid.

The loop is not readable. It is a law in programming that a non-readable code contains a bug.

Make the code more simpler and more readable.